# Will this site get a dark mode?

Tags: feature-request

That's it, that's the question. Can we get a dark mode? I am reluctant to use these dark-mode Chrome extensions, and I think all the StackExchange sites should have a dark mode, regardless.

Comment: Considering how far behind the company is on designs, I am doubtful

Comment: If SU does it, the mode must be optional.  I prefer to be able to read properly = light mode.

Comment: The company turns to the dark side, not to a dark mode.

Comment: TL;DR: It might get implemented at some point in the future, but the Design team's not currently working on implementing a dark mode for sites other than SO (particularly those with custom themes).